# Shared memory between multiple nodes pytorch

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing

I try to create a memory bank to store image features along with their labels. I am utilizing 2 nodes, each equipped with 4 GPUs. I aim for this memory bank to be shared among all processes and be used for updates during training.

I have this code snippet

```
@torch.no_grad()
def eval_build_bank(model, data_loader, len_dataset, device, world_size):
    features = torch.zeros(len_dataset, model.model.visual.classifier.shape[0]).to(device)
    labels   = torch.zeros(len_dataset, dtype=torch.long).to(device)
    for _, batch in enumerate(data_loader):
        inputs, _, idx = batch
        image = inputs[0].to(device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            logit, feats = model(image)
        features[idx] = feats.detach()
        proba = torch.softmax(logit, dim=-1)
        pseudo_targets = torch.argmax(proba, dim=-1)
        labels[idx] = pseudo_targets.detach()
    dist.all_reduce(features, op=dist.ReduceOp.SUM)
    dist.all_reduce(labels, op=dist.ReduceOp.SUM)
    bank = {
        "features" : features,
        "labels" : labels
    } 
    return bank
```

Is this correct?